# Приложение при переходе из одного activity в другое выдаёт ошибку:E/DropboxRealtime: null InputStream java.io.IOException: null InputStream

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Ниже приведен код данного activity

```
    package com.example.chernovik;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    // путь к базе данных вашего приложения
    private static String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.chernovik/DataBase.db/";
    public static String DB_NAME="DataBase.db";
    static final String TABLE = "Data";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    static final String COLUMN_NAME = "data";
    private final Context mContext;


    /**
     * Конструктор
     * Принимает и сохраняет ссылку на переданный контекст для доступа к ресурсам приложения
     */

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
        DB_PATH=mContext.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Создает пустую базу данных и перезаписывает ее нашей собственной базой
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();


            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }

        }
        else{
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();


            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException{

        this.getReadableDatabase();


        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }


    }




    /**
     * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
     * @return true если существует, false если не существует
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
     * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    }
}
```

Так ниже показан класс, в котором создается база данных

```
package com.example.chernovik;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    // путь к базе данных вашего приложения
    private static String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.chernovik/DataBase.db/";
    public static String DB_NAME="DataBase.db";
    static final String TABLE = "Data";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    static final String COLUMN_NAME = "data";
    private final Context mContext;


    /**
     * Конструктор
     * Принимает и сохраняет ссылку на переданный контекст для доступа к ресурсам приложения
     */

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
        DB_PATH=mContext.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Создает пустую базу данных и перезаписывает ее нашей собственной базой
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();


            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }

        }
        else{
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();


            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException{

        this.getReadableDatabase();


        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }


    }




    /**
     * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
     * @return true если существует, false если не существует
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
     * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Так же добавляю стектрейс:

```
10284-10284/com.example.chernovik E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.chernovik, PID: 10284
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chernovik/com.example.chernovik.ActivityList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2821)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.chernovik.ActivityList.<init>(ActivityList.java:62)
                                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: а стектрейс где?

Comment: @Виктор Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chernovik/com.example.chernovik.ActivityList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: выложите в пост весь стектрейс.

Comment: @Виктор выложил

Comment: У вас в место кода активити просто продублирован код класса `DataBaseHelper` . А ошибка из-за того, что пытаетесь получить текст методом `.getText()` у несуществующей ссылки на объект

Comment: @Данил благодарю